# How can I pass and than get the passed arguments in databricks job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-workflows, databricks-dbx

I'm trying to pass and get arguments in my databricks job it's a spark_python_task type IT IS NOT A NOTEBOOK. I deployed my job with dbx from pycharm. I have deployment.json file where I configure deployment stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow [documentation about deployment file](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#preparing-deployment-file), you can see that you can specify parameters as `parameters` array:

```json
{
  "name": "this-parameter-is-required!",
  "spark_python_task": {
      "python_file": "path/to/entrypoint.py" 
  },
  "parameters": [
     "--conf-file",
     "conf/test/sample.json"
  ]
}
```

Parameters are passed as command-line parameters, so you can get them from the code just using the [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.argv), or [built-in argparse library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html).

Comment: When I make this I receive the path of this json as arguments not the elements from the json. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: yes - arguments are just whatever you pass. If you have data in file, you need to read them yourself