# Running local python code with arguments in Databricks via dbx utility

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-dbx

I am trying to execute a local PySpark script on a Databricks cluster via dbx utility to test how passing arguments to python works in Databricks when developing locally. However, the test arguments I am passing are not being read for some reason. Could someone help?
Following this guide, but it is a bit unclear and lacks good examples.
https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html
Found this, but it also not clear: [How can I pass and than get the passed arguments in databricks job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685689/how-can-i-pass-and-than-get-the-passed-arguments-in-databricks-job)

Databricks manuals are very much not clear in this area.

My PySpark script:

```
import sys

n = len(sys.argv)
print("Total arguments passed:", n)

print("Script name", sys.argv[0])

print("\nArguments passed:", end=" ")
for i in range(1, n):
    print(sys.argv[i], end=" ")
```

dbx deployment.json:

```
{
  "default": {
    "jobs": [
      {
        "name": "parameter-test",
        "spark_python_task": {
            "python_file": "parameter-test.py"
        },
        "parameters": [
          "test-argument-1",
          "test-argument-2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

dbx execute command:

```
dbx execute\
  --cluster-id=<reducted>\
  --job=parameter-test\
  --deployment-file=conf/deployment.json\
  --no-rebuild\
  --no-package
```

Output:

```
(parameter-test) user@735 parameter-test % /bin/zsh /Users/user/g-drive/git/parameter-test/parameter-test.sh
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:33.864] Using profile provided from the project file
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:33.866] Found auth config from provider ProfileEnvConfigProvider, verifying it
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:33.866] Found auth config from provider ProfileEnvConfigProvider, verification successful
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:33.866] Profile DEFAULT will be used for deployment
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:35.897] Executing job: parameter-test in environment default on cluster None (id: 0513-204842-7b2r325u)
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:35.897] No rebuild will be done, please ensure that the package distribution is in dist folder
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:35.897] Using the provided deployment file conf/deployment.json
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:35.899] Preparing interactive cluster to accept jobs
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:35.997] Cluster is ready
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:35.998] Preparing execution context
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:36.534] Existing context is active, using it
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:36.992] Requirements file requirements.txt is not provided, following the execution without any additional packages
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:36.992] Package was disabled via --no-package, only the code from entrypoint will be used
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:37.161] Processing parameters
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:37.449] Processing parameters - done
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:37.449] Starting entrypoint file execution
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:37.767] Command successfully executed
Total arguments passed: 1
Script name python

Arguments passed:
[dbx][2022-07-26 10:34:37.768] Command execution finished
(parameter-test) user@735 parameter-test %
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the parameter section format of my deployment.json was not correct. Here is the corrected example:

```
{
  "default": {
    "jobs": [
      {
        "name": "parameter-test",
        "spark_python_task": {
          "python_file": "parameter-test.py",
          "parameters": [
            "test1",
            "test2"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've also posted my original question in Databricks forum: https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D58Y00008znXBxSAM?t=1659032862560
Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I also believe the "jobs" parameter is deprecated and you should use "workflows" instead.

Source: https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration/